# Using PHPUnit with Selenium, how can I test that an element contains exactly something?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit and Selenium, and currently using something like `$this->assertElementContainsText('id=foo', 'bar')` which passes when it finds this: `<p id="foo">bar</p>`

However, I am also trying to test for a case where `p#foo` might contain other HTML, and I want to test that the contents matches *exactly*. In my mind, it would look something like `$this->assertElementTextEquals('id=foo', '<a href="http://www.example.com/">bar</a>')`.

Is there an existing way to achieve this with PHPUnit and Selenium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass in any Xpath to target the desired element.

```
$this->assertElementContainsText(
    "//p[@id='foo']/a[@href='http://www.example.com/']",
    'bar'
);
```

You can add the following to your base class to allow testing for exact matches on the contents.

```
/**
 * Asserts that an element contains exactly a given string.
 *
 * @param  string $locator
 * @param  string $text
 * @param  string $message
 */
public function assertElementTextEquals($locator, $text, $message = '')
{
    $this->assertEquals($text, $this->getText($locator), $message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Xpath and it seems to be working great. (I wish Selenium offered a way to get the complete HTML contents of a given locator, but I can't seem to find one.)