# Cannot call a command with multiple method arguments

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

Every time I attempt to use one of the basic PHPUnit Selenium assertions, the tests errors out and displays this message:

```
Exception: You cannot call a command with multiple method arguments.
```

On http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html, it shows the usage to be:

```
void assertElementValueEquals(string $locator, string $text)
```

Be when I call it with

```
$this->assertElementValueEquals( 'id=date_1_formatted', '2013-01-01' );
```

the test produces the above error every time even though this same format seems to be working for others such as in the question [Using PHPUnit with Selenium, how can I test that an element contains exactly something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185029/using-phpunit-with-selenium-how-can-i-test-that-an-element-contains-exactly-som)

Comment: I'd suggest either trying `'#date_1_formatted'` or `"[id='date_1_formatted']"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but each of those still produces the same error.

Comment: I can't find any specific documentation that calls out explicitly what `$locator` is supposed to be, but it's possible that it only accepts xpath.  In which case, I'd try `"//[@id='date_1_formatted']"`

Comment: No difference.  I've got a work-around using $this->byXPath( '//input[@value="2013-01-01"]' ) inside a try/catch block to determine if an element with that value exists.  Not a great way to do it, but it works for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*assertElementValueEquals* is not implemented in **Selenium2TestCase**. On your link it mentioned for **SeleniumTestCase** (Selenium RC version).

Moreover, you used correct structure with $this->byXPath like here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php

Also you can use *$this->byId()*:

```
$element = $this->byId('date_1_formatted');
$this->assertEquals('2013-01-01', $element->value());
```

P. S.: If you are familiar with Selenium IDE, you can try this [command line tool](https://github.com/rnixik/selenium2php).

Comment: If you want to get the value contained in between the opening and closing tags as for example get `Hello` in `<a href="example.com">Hello</a>` use `$element->text()` assuming `$element` is the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

Walked into this one too, in my case it was my *own* custom method, so I thought it was a line off.
Turns out I was using a different "buffer" class between the test class and the phpunit than I thought. But because it uses __call() a Lot, it gave ↑ that error instead of "undefined method".